# react-bootstrap-typeahead How do I trigger a callback (update state) on `Enter` but not when the user is selecting hint?

Tags: react-bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to make an input that will allow user to select multiple items. When finished selecting, he can press `Enter` to push his selections into an array in the state. The input will then clear and be ready for his next set of selections. (Imagine populating a 2-d array quickly). However, with the code below, if the user presses `Enter` to select the hint, my callback, `pushToState`, will trigger as it's in `onKeyDown`. What's the correct way to implement this behavior?

```
<Typeahead
  id="basic-typeahead-multiple"
  labelKey="name"
  multiple
  onChange={setMultiSelections}
  options={options}
  selected={multiSelections}
  onKeyDown={(event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      pushToState(multiSelections);
      setMultiSelections([]);
    }
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case is similar to [the one in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63275021/react-bootstrap-typeahead-handling-enter-key-if-no-menu-item-selected/63290045). You basically need to determine whether the user is selecting a menu item or not. You can do that by checking the `activeIndex` of the typeahead:

```jsx
// Track the index of the highlighted menu item.
const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(-1);

const onKeyDown = useCallback(
  (e) => {
    // Check whether the 'enter' key was pressed, and also make sure that
    // no menu items are highlighted.
    if (event.key === 'Enter' && activeIndex === -1) {
      pushToState(multiSelections);
      setMultiSelections([]);
    }
  },
  [activeIndex]
);

return (
  <Typeahead
    id="basic-typeahead-multiple"
    labelKey="name"
    multiple
    onChange={setMultiSelections}
    options={options}
    onChange={setMultiSelections}
    onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
    selected={multiSelections} >
    {(state) => {
      // Passing a child render function to the component exposes partial
      // internal state, including the index of the highlighted menu item.
      setActiveIndex(state.activeIndex);
    }}
  </Typeahead>
);
```

Comment: Thank you. I neglected the </Typeahead> which caused much pain. Is the child function (state) => {..} documented anywhere?

Comment: @mrkent it's documented here: https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/docs/API.md#children

Comment: @ ericgio By adding the `setActiveIndex(state.activeIndex)` in the inner function, I'm getting these warnings: `Cannot update a component ('FormExample') while rendering a different component ('RootClose').` described here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18178#issuecomment-595846312 . It doesn't seem to cause any issue in my app, but is this something you expect? React 16.13.1 and typeahead 5.1.1 if at all useful.

Comment: Sorry but one more question. `activeIndex` doesn't update if `highlightOnlyResult` is set to true. Can this behavior be achieved with `highlightOnlyResult`?

Comment: @mrkent: I haven't seen that react issue before, but I would trust what it says. It may be possible that this workaround won't work with future versions of React. My answer really is just an attempt at a workaround, since yours isn't a primary use case supported by the component. I definitely have not tested it under all conditions and don't make guarantees as to how well it works in various scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to do it by `ref`.

```
const ref = createRef<TypeaheadRef>()

const handleKeyDown = (e: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
  if (e.code === 'Enter' && ref.current?.state.activeIndex === -1) {
    // ... 
  }
}

return (
  <Typeahead
    ref={ref}
    id="basic-typeahead-multiple"
    labelKey="name"
    multiple
    onChange={setMultiSelections}
    options={options}
    selected={multiSelections}
    onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
  />
)
```